# Create new object from array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create new object with different properties name from Array.

Array is:

```
profiles: Array(1)
   0:
    column:
        name: "profileName"
        title: "Profile name"
    status: "Active"
```

I want to create new function that return object with two properties:

id: 'profileName',
profileStatus: 'Active'

The function that I have create is returning only one property as undefined undefined=undefined.

```
function getProfile(profiles) {
    if (!profiles.length) return undefined;

    return profiles.reduce((obj, profile) => {
        console.log('profiles', profile);
        return ({
          ...obj,
          id: profile.column.name,
          profileStatus: profile.status,
        });
      }, {});
}
```

The function getProfile is taking as input array 'profiles' from outside,

Comment: You wrote "profiles" instead of "profile" in the reduce method.

Comment: your item is called profile and you are accessing the array "profiles"

Comment: opps, my mistake where I did ask. Is not the issue here

Comment: Definitely would cause the undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested here and this seems to be working actually

```
const getProfile1 = (p) => p.reduce((obj, profile) =>({
    ...obj,
    id: profile.column.name,
    profileStatus: profile.status,
}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map as an alternative.

```js
var profiles = [{"column":{"name": "profileName3","title": "3Profile name"},"status": "Active"},{"column":{"name": "profileName","title": "Profile name"},"status": "Active"}];

function getProfile(profiles) {
    if (!profiles.length) return undefined;
    return profiles.map(function(profile,v){
      return {id:profile.column.name,profileStatus: profile.status};
   });

}

console.log(getProfile(profiles));
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I use `reduce` in this way, I usually index the final object by some sort of an `id`. As noted in another answer, you could use `map` in this situation as well. If you really want your final data structure to be an object, however, you could do something like this:

```
/**
 * returns object indexed by profile id
 */
const formatProfiles = (profiles) => {
  return profiles.reduce((obj, profile) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [profile.id]: {
        id: profile.column.name,
        profileStatus: profile.status,
      }
    };
  }, {});
};

const profiles = [
  {
    id: 0,
    status: 'active',
    column: {
      name: "profile_name_1",
      title: "profile_title_1",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    status: 'inactive',
    column: {
      name: "profile_name_2",
      title: "profile_title_2",
    }
  }
];

const result = formatProfiles(profiles);

/**
 * Result would look like this:
 */
// {
//   '0': { id: 'profile_name_1', profileStatus: 'active' },
//   '1': { id: 'profile_name_2', profileStatus: 'inactive' }
// }
```